# What is the difference between equality-preserving and stable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts

According to the [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/concepts.equality):

> An expression is **equality-preserving** if, given equal inputs, the expression results in equal outputs.[...]

and

> [...]**stable**: two evaluations of such an expression with the same input objects are required to have equal outputs absent any explicit intervening modification of those input objects.[...]

emphasis mine.

- What's the difference between these?
- When an expression can be *equality-preserving* but not *stable* and *vice-versa*?

Comment: The input objects don't have to be equal for 'stable'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two would be different for an operation that modified its inputs.

```
// stable and equality preserving
int foo(int a, int b) { 
    return a + b;
}

// equality preserving, but not stable:
int bar(int a, int &b) { 
    auto ret = a + b;
    ++b;
    return ret;
}
```

For example:

```
int x = 1, y = 2;
int z = foo(x, y); // produces 3

int z2 = foo(x, y);  // still produces 3

int zz = bar(x, y); // produces 3
int zz2 = bar(x, y); // produces 4
```

As for something that was stable but not equality preserving, yes, that's also possible (for some definitions of "equal").

For a trivial example, consider something like this:

```
struct foo { 
    int bar;

    // they're all equal, just some are more equal than others
    bool operator==(foo const &) const { return true; }
};

int operator+(foo a, foo b) { return a.bar + b.bar; }

foo a{1};
foo b{2};
foo c{3};

// obviously both true
assert(a == b);
assert(b == c);

int x = a + b;
int y = b + c;

assert(x != y); // of course 1 + 2 != 2 + 3;
```

Comment: Great! this clarifies "_equality-preserving_ but not _stable_" case. Is the opposite case possible?

Comment: @Nazinho no it's not. Whenever it is stable, it is equality preserving as well.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin I hope in the future the standard make it clear what definition of 'equal' they refer to. Anyways this text isn't normative.

Comment: @Nazinho The value of an object is a purely subjective property. You can define the "value" of `String` object in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

The approved answer is incorrect.
This function:

```
int foo(int a, int b) { 
    return a + b;
}
```

is indeed equality-preserving and stable.
But so is this function:

```
int bar(int a, int &b) { 
    auto ret = a + b;
    ++b;
    return ret;
}
```

The actual difference between the two is that foo is regular (cf concept regular_invocable) but bar is not.

An example of a function that is equality-preserving but not stable is:

```
int b = 0;  // assume accessible by other threads
int zip(int a) { 
    auto ret = a + b;
    ++b;
    return ret;
}
```

It is equality-preserving because equality-preservation is purely *static*, and at any given time, zip will indeed give the same result with the same input.

However, zip is not stable because stability is *dynamic*, and at different times, zip *may* give different results with the same input.

(If the global variable b was unchanged in-between the calls, then it will give a different result. But if another thread decremented b, and no other change occurred, it will give the same result.)

(If no other thread could access the b variable, notwithstanding how this can be achieved practically, we would have stability, because we could observe an "explicit intervening modification". This the reason the standard mentions that stability prohibits "spontaneous" changes, aka volatility, changes from other threads of execution, and so on. Cf concepts.lib.general.equality)

Also note that equality-preservation does not depend on the availability of an equality operator (and the equality_comparable concept actually requires equality preservation). Equality is not explicitly defined, but should be considered as substitutability, or indistinguishability, which is often mentioned by the standard, such as in strong_ordering.

A function cannot be stable without being equality-preserving, since stability is the dynamic extension of the static notion of equality-preservation.

Comment: From the standard: ‘Expressions required to be equality-preserving are further required to be stable: two evaluations of such an expression with the same input objects are required to have equal outputs absent any explicit intervening modification of those input objects.’ Apparently two evaluations of `bar` won't have equal outputs, so I do not agree with your interpretation.

Comment: But the key is that the same outputs must be returned *absent any explicit intervening modification of those input objects*. And in the case of the second invocation of bar, there has been an "explicit intervening modification" of input &b, namely in the first invocation of bar. So the requirement of "same output" is inapplicable.

Comment: To be clearer, in this case (successive invocation), stability for `bar` is satisfied but in a vacuous manner, however, stability applies more generally. The invocations are required to return the same result, absent modification of inputs, not only when they are "time-ordered" between each other (i.e. when one precedes the other), but also when no such relationship exists between them.

Comment: The stability of `bar` can be seen in that performing an invocation at time `t` or performing one at a later time `s` will result in the same outputs; but only absent any modification of inputs in the interval, which, therefore, precludes, doing an invocation at time `s` followed by an invocation at time `t`. Taking this into consideration, we indeed have that invoking at time `s` returns the same outputs as those that *would have been* returned *otherwise* at time `t`.